# Validate combination of codes with clause operators

Tags: python, java, sql, conditional-statements, operators

First of all, I'm sorry this question may sound easy, but I'm not a real programmer, just a hobbyist.

I have a problem I can't get around solving how to program following thing in any available language or even Excel. I can do it myself in java, but I'm guessing it is fairly simple to do in py. So here goes:

Say you have a condition clause that determines *something*. Here comes the clause:

`(100/200)+ABC+(AAA/BBB)+-(CCC/DDD)`

Here the operators act in certain way, so that if *any* of these combinations match the dataset, it's a match. I have to extract the logic of the operators in the clause string, as they are used in the logic to produce the possible combinations. I'm assuming + operator is used as including/AND and minus operator means without /IS NOT. Then / operator is used as OR operator.

Here comes all the combinations of the clause:

```
| 100 + ABC + AAA - CCC - DDD
| 100 + ABC + BBB - CCC - DDD
| 200 + ABC + AAA - CCC - DDD
| 200 + ABC + BBB - CCC - DDD
```

Let's say my dataset contains the following values (stored in .csv file)

> ;100;ABC;AAA;    // this matches first combination
>
> ;100;ABC;AAA;CCC // this does not match any, since it contains CCC

I hope that was not too messy write up! Been thinking my head through on this one. Thanks in advance!

I can't get around grasping the logic of the operators. I've thought about binary approach, but it could be some sort of SQL logic.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution Regex:

Use Regex to find all matches of an `expression` or "conditional clause" in a String. The following regular Expression will match against any character sequences

### Statement

In short, the full statement, you have to match against looks like this:

```
(100|200);ABC;(AAA|BBB)(?:(?!(CCC|DDD))).$
```

#### Explanation

- `(100|200)` -> beginning either with '100' or '200'
- `;` -> followed by a ';' as a delimeter
- `ABC` -> followed by the character group 'ABC'
- `;` -> followed again by the delimiter
- `(AAA|BBB)` -> followed by either 'AAA' or 'BBB'

The next part of the expression seems a little cryptic, so here comes a more detailed explanation:

- `(?:` -> marks the beginning of a non capturing group
- `(?!` -> negative lookahead (Asserts that the following Regex does not match)
- `(CCC|DDD)` -> matches to Strings 'CCC' and 'DDD' (referred to, by the negative lookahead)
- `))` -> end of the non capturing group and negative lookahead
- `.` -> matches any character (except for line terminators) might have to be changed into the delimiter `;` for a more specific query or removed entirely based on what your data actually looks like and what you want
- `$` -> matches the end of a line

## Implementation

### Python:

Python enables you to easily evaluate Regular Expressions using the library `re`. It should already be a part of the Vanilla version of `python3`:

```
import re

my_string = '|100;ABC;AAA;
|100;ABC;BBB;
|200;ABC;AAA;
|200;ABC;AAA'
my_expression = '(100|200);ABC;(AAA|BBB)(?:(?!(CCC|DDD))).$'


res = re.findall(my_expression, my_string)
print([r for r in res])
```

### Java

However Java can do Regex operations as well:

```
import java.util.regex.*;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(100|200);ABC;(AAA|BBB)(?:(?!(CCC|DDD))).$");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= regexMatcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            // matched text: regexMatcher.group(i)
            // match start: regexMatcher.start(i)
            // match end: regexMatcher.end(i)
        }
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

#### Testing

You can easily test and develop regular expressions on [this website](https://regex101.com). It makes it easy to learn the expressions since every element of your expression will be explained on the side. You can run it against your own custom Strings.